# Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 - trouble using POST method

Tags: php, reactjs

I'm rewriting my complaint management system app into one using react and fetch() api, when i am trying to update my database with data i get the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0"

I Have tried the common fixes like adding headers Accept and Content-Type, checked fetch adress if it is correct. In addition other fetches that i use work correctly, i got trouble with sending POST with a body

```js
 fetch('http://localhost/system_reklamacji/php/zmien.php',{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        klucz_nr: sel.target.id,
        klucz_idprac: sel.target.value,
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json()).then((msg)=> console.log(msg))
}
```

Here is my php file

```php
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
print_r($data);


$reklamacja=$_POST['klucz_nr'];// tried those as weel
$pracownik =$_POST['klucz_idprac'];//yeah



 $zapytanie_wyslij = "UPDATE rtransportowa SET ID_U = '".$pracownik."', "; 
if($pracownik=='0')
{
    $zapytanie_wyslij.="STATUS = 'nieprzypisane'";
}
else{
 $zapytanie_wyslij.=" STATUS='przypisane'";

}
$zapytanie_wyslij.=" WHERE NR_REKLAMACJI = '".$reklamacja."'";
    //printf($zapytanie_wyslij);

$wynik_wyslij = mysqli_query($db, $zapytanie_wyslij);
```

Comment: The error you're getting is because your PHP file doesn't output valid json while your JS expects it to. For example, the line `print_r($data);` will mess it up. I also don't see where you're actually output anything else? Open the network tab in your browsers console, then make a request and check what data it sends and what the response from the PHP file actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem with `response.json()` in below line only.

```
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((msg)=> console.log(msg))
```

Can you please check the response of the API call. Make sure response should be in `object` not `string` or `undefined`.

Comment: Deleting the ```(response) =>response.json()``` seems to work, there is no warnings anymore. However i am not able to get anything done with my php, table is not getting updated, is `$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$reklamacja=$data->{'klucz_nr'};
$pracownik=$data->{'klucz_idprac'};` correct way of decoding the data?